# How to resize-image without changing aspect-ratio and cropping image

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I am trying to resize a background image using CSS only, by keeping it's aspect-ratio unchanged and no image cropping from any side

I tried 
background-size: cover; // it is cropping image from sides while resizing browser

background-size: 100% 100%; // it is shrinking image and it's aspect ratio is gone for actual image but canvas of image is intact with it's aspect ratio

```
.class {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
```

```
.class {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Image should not get cropped or shrink while resizing browser/mobile devices, strictly keeping it's aspect ratio.

Comment: try `contain` instead of `cover`: - [**contain**:
Scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: This seems to assume that the image has the same aspect ratio as the div...what if it doesn't? I don't think you can avoid both **at the same time**.

Comment: tried : contain, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Then you need to think about what you want - as paulie says, you cannot keep your aspect ratio and cover everything without the image being cropped,  unless your element remains the same aspect ratio as the image in every browser size

Comment: I even tried height and width along with max-height and max-width, it's also not working for me

I can not keep my div in px or image in px

Comment: if you set the width to 100%, set the height to "auto" - that will preserve the aspect ratio. background size w/h are set to auto by default to preserve aspect ratio, but you can use contain also

Comment: What do you want to happen when, e.g. the div is wider than the background image? Not [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/m1x6e8kq/4/), obviously.

Comment: @RachelGallen I did same, removed fixed height of the div and set its as 
height: auto; 
object-fit: cover;

and it worked for me.

Thanks a lot to all, for prompt update